# A question regarding image and pre - image of Mobius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it due to lack of time. I am looking for an alternative method than mine.

> Question: Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d\in\mathbb{C}$ be such that $ad-bc>0$. Consider the Möbius transformation $T(z)= \frac{az+b} {cz+d}$ . Define $H_{+}=\{z \in  \mathbb{C}\mid Im(z)>0\}$, $H_{-}=\{z \in\mathbb{C}\mid Im(z)<0\}$, $R_{+}=\{z \in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)>0\}$, $R_{-}=\{z \in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)<0\}$:

Then $T(z)$ maps

(i) $H_{+} \mapsto H_{+}$

(ii)$ H_{+} \mapsto H_{-}$

(iii) $R_{+} \mapsto R_{+}$

(iv)$R_{+} \mapsto R_{-}$

Its a single correct answer.

Attempt : I tried by writing $z$ as $x+iy$ in $T(z)$ and then removing iota from the denominator by multiplying and dividing by $(cx+d-iy)$ but I think thats a very lenghty method.

Can you please tell me alternative and relatively short method.

Thanks!!

Comment: What does this question have to do with polynomial rings and euclidean domains in the title?

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you supposed to show which of (i-iv) hold because it can't be that both (i) and (ii) hold, or that both (iii) and (iv) hold at the same time. For example, if $a=1$, $b=c=0$ and $d=1$, then $T(z)=z$ so (ii) and (iv) do not hold.

Comment: Probably, you should consider that $a,b,c,d$ are **real**.

Comment: Consider $(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(1,-100,0,1)$.